# How to round away from zero

Tags: python, numpy, math, rounding

I am new to python, and as far as I found out, python doesn't have sort of "mathematical" rounding. Or does it have?
I have a temperature array, for example:

```
temp = [-20.5, -21.5, -22.5, -23.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5]
```

I couldn't fine the way to round values mathematically to:

```
>> [-21, -21, -22, -22, -22, -24, -23, -23, -23, -23, -24, ...]
```

So that -20.5 rounded to -21, -21.5 rounded to -22, -23.5 rounded to -24, 10.5 rounded to 11, 11.5 rounded to 12, 12.5 rounded to 13. Mathematical accuracy is important in my case.

The best option for me is using function like numpy.around() due to it does rounding for all the values at ones, not one by one (I suppose, it is faster). Is there such a function, or such a way at all?

Results i got:

```
np.around(temp, decimals=0)
>>[-20. -22. -22. -24.  10.  12.  12.  14.]
np.rint(temp)
>>[-20. -22. -22. -24.  10.  12.  12.  14.]
np.round(temp)
>>[-20. -22. -22. -24.  10.  12.  12.  14.]
np.trunc(temp)
>>[-20. -21. -22. -23.  10.  11.  12.  13.]
```

Comment: What about [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)?

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding); the one you are describing is called "round half away from zero".

Comment: Test cases including with (+/-)n.4 would be useful to disambiguate between round half away from zero and round away from zero. You also mentioned the efficiency of rounding many values at once, vs one by one. Of course either way there's a loop involved; either one you write, or one implicit in the function you use from a library. Is a microoptimization needed here?

Comment: Correct your target array (so it matches the text).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy` has a `around`, which documents:

```
Notes
-----
For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0,
-0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due
to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE
floating point standard [1]_ and errors introduced when scaling
by powers of ten.
```

Rounding to nearest even is just as valid, mathematically, as rounding away from zero.  The purpose of such rules is to provide consistency, and some degree of statistical uniformity (reduce bias).

But it also warns that float values are seldom 'exactly' half's.  We frequently get questions about values that display like `20.49999999`.

===

A numpy version of the `round_away_from_zero` function in the other answer:

```
def round_away(x):
    a = np.abs(x)
    b = np.floor(a) + np.floor(2*(a%1))
    return np.sign(x)*b

In [279]: np.array(temp)                                                        
Out[279]: array([-20.5, -21.5, -22.5, -23.5,  10.5,  11.5,  12.5,  13.5])
In [280]: round_away(temp)                                                      
Out[280]: array([-21., -22., -23., -24.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.])
```

Comment: I could understand such rules. Unfortunately, my job requires me to tell values rounded mathematically, not by that "financial" rounding. I will be blamed if I say, that 2.5 rounded is 2. Values I work with have only 1 decimal, nothing like 20.49999999

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you  very much! Could you briefly describe, what's going on inside the function?

Answer (score 2):

as *chepner* said, the type of rounding you describing is **round away from zero**.

you could do the following:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def round_away_from_zero(x):
    a = abs(x)
    r = math.floor(a) + math.floor(2 * (a % 1))
    return r if x >= 0 else -r

temp = [-20.5, -21.5, -22.5, -23.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5]
temp_np = np.array(temp)
t = map(round_away_from_zero, temp_np)
print(t)
```

the output you get is:

> [-21.0, -22.0, -23.0, -24.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0]

**Note**

follwoing the user comment Ill briefly explain about `np.array()` and `map()`:

1. `np.array()`: this function takes an array object and transform it to a Numpy object allowing to use functionality that associated with it, you can read about it in the following [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)
2. `map()`:  function is used to apply a function on all the elements of specified iterable and return map object. Python map object is an iterator, so we can iterate over its elements. We can also convert map object to sequence objects such as list, tuple etc.

Comment: I wrote a numpy version of your `round_away_from_zero`.  For larger arrays this will be faster than your `list(map(...)` application.

Comment: Unfortunately, because I'm new to python, I don't quite understand the code, particularly the part about **"map", "np.array()" function, mathematical operations inside rounding function**. Might you briefly tell me, what's going on there? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this is the output I get: `<map object at 0x03AB9B10>.`

Comment: @ David S , thank you very much, now it's all clear!

Answer (score 1):

Late but here's a clever(?) way:

```
arr = np.array([1.2, -1.2])
arr_rounded = np.copysign(np.ceil(np.abs(arr)), arr)
```

Output being: [2, -2]